# How to simplify a VLOOKUP formula with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a `VLOOKUP` formula which needs to return true or false depending on certain conditions in another worksheet *Sheet2*.

In *Sheet2*, a cell can either be *blank*, contain a *zero* or a *number*.

My formula needs to return `TRUE` if the cell has a *number* or is *blank*, and `FALSE` if the cell contains a *zero*. I thought the following formula would work, but it's assuming zero is blank and so returns false for both zero and blank cells.

```
VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!$A$2:$J$100,10, FALSE)<>0
```

I can solve this by using an `OR` statement, like this:

```
OR(VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!$A$2:$J$100,10, FALSE)<>0,
VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!$A$2:$J$100,10, FALSE)= "")
```

But I want to know if there is a way of doing this which does not require writing out the whole `VLOOKUP` formula twice. In other words, is there a way to simplify this?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=NOT(LEFT(VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!$A$2:$J$100,10, FALSE),8192)="0")
```

Just compares the left 8192 char of the text string match to "0" and inverts. Although it would work with any number greater than 1, I chose 8192 is because that is the max cell length allowed in excel. Bonus :P

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
=IFERROR(--(""&VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!$A$2:$J$100,10, FALSE)),1)<>0
```